# Can a universal quantifier be applied to statements including equality?

Tags: logic

The example I found on this site is as follows (this is specifying that some property holds for exactly two things):

∃x∃y((x≠y∧P(x)∧P(y))∧∀z(P(z)→(z=x∨z=y)))

The problem I'm having is that trying to negate this ends up starting like this:

∀x∀y(x=y), which doesn't make sense to me (intuitively), even though the initial statement does. How can a universal quantifier be applied to equality?

Also, a second question, does the negation of the initial statement need to be an exhaustive negation?

For example, if I were to say x=2, would saying x>2 be a sufficient negation? Or would you need to specify (x>2∨x<2)?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first question, the problem is resolved if you write out the entire negation:

$$
\forall x\forall y((x=y\lor\neg P(x)\lor\neg P(y))\lor\exists z((z\ne x\land z\ne y)\land P(z)))\;.
$$

Now the equality makes perfect sense: Either $x$ and $y$ are equal, or the property doesn't hold for one of them, or there's a $z$ different from both for which the property holds.

I'm not sure I understand the context of your second question properly, but if it refers to finding the logical negation of a statement, $x\gt2$ is not a negation of $x=2$; the only negation is $x\ne2$.